Getting some error while installing spflow
Collecting spflow
  Using cached spflow-0.0.41-py3-none-any.whl (244 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spflow) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spflow) (1.11.4)
Collecting sklearn (from spflow)
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post12.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I am getting this error while installing spflow (pip install spflow).
I have already installed scikit-learn (not sklearn).

The spflow package published on PyPi incorrectly has sklearn as a requirement, which is deprecated. Fortunately, this has been fixed on github, so you can try to install from there:
pip install https://github.com/SPFlow/SPFlow/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

